# SQL Server - Retrieve monthly data (not accumulated)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two fields

DATE_YYYYMM
TOTAL

That table contains the accumulated total per month for the whole year.
I'd like a query retrieving the "unacumulated" total for each month.

For example, the total of 201806 would be equal to the total of 201806 minus the one of 201805.

Any tip please ? Thanks !

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Any sample data? Expected results? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The window function [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) can be used to get a previous value based on an order.

And it seems you just want to subtract the previous month's total from the total.

```
SELECT 
DATE_YYYYMM, 
TOTAL,
TOTAL - ISNULL(LAG(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_YYYYMM), 0) AS UNACCUMULATED
FROM YourYearTotalsTable
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic function LAG (starting from sql-server-2012) to compare values in the current row with values in a previous row.

```
SELECT
     [date_yyyymm]
    ,[current_total] = [total]
    ,[previous_total] = LAG([total], 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [date_yyyymm])
    ,[unacumulated] = [total] - LAG([total], 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [date_yyyymm])
FROM [your_table]
ORDER BY [date_yyyymm];
```